# Como adicionar uma nova Runnable a um ExecutorService?

Tags: java, thread, ejb, extensão

É a primeira vez que trabalho com threads...
   O método abaixo é executado de 15 em 15 segundos pelo EJB.
   Eu queria que se caso houver lista de SMS no banco ele adicionasse a uma nova thread de disparo desses SMS

Porem está retornando o seguinte erro:

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task com.core.framework.timerservice.TimerSessionBeanSmsLote$1@1e13b49e rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1945ea4f[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
10:29:17,342 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 1) JBAS014122: Error during retrying timeout for timer: [id=f3aba899-a38f-4111-bbc6-2465b9dfcbf0 timedObjectId=PortalEAR.PortalEJB.TimerSessionBeanSmsLote auto-timer?:true persistent?:true timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@2a060c86 initialExpiration=Thu Oct 09 00:00:00 BRT 2014 intervalDuration(in milli sec)=0 nextExpiration=Wed Oct 15 05:07:45 BRT 2014 timerState=IN_TIMEOUT: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task com.core.framework.timerservice.TimerSessionBeanSmsLote$1@1ad48394 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1945ea4f[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
```

Segue o código:

```
@Singleton
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class TimerSessionBeanSmsLote {

    private ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    private List smsLoteList;

    // Esse método é executado de 15 em 15 segundos.........
    @Schedule(hour="*", minute="*", second="*/15") 
    @AccessTimeout(value = 20, unit = TimeUnit.DAYS)
    public void automaticTimeout()  {
        // pega a lista de sms no banco.............
        smsLoteList = buscaOsSMSnoBANCO();

        if(!smsLoteList.isEmpty()){
            service.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   //Envia SMS.............
                }
            });
            service.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quando você faz `service.shutdown()`, o `ExecutorService` passa a rejeitar tasks e dispara esta exceção. Também pode rejeitar se o limite de tasks for atingido; você setou este limite para 10 - sempre será o bastante? Por fim, você precisa mesmo que este processo execute em outra thread?

Comment: Jamais inicialize threads não administradas pelo container em um EJB. Use a nova API de concorrência:http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/concurrency-utilities.htm

Comment: Finalmente, não vejo necessidade de trabalhar com threads aqui. Um novo session bean (não singleton) com um método assíncrono para enviar SMS garantiria a concorrência.

Answer (score 1):

O modo como você adicionou o `Runnable` está correto e a forma de poder adicionar uma nova é não invocando `service.shutdown()`.

Itso responde sua pergunta. Removendo dali o `service.shutdown()` você não terá mais esta exceção.

Todavia, você não parece ter um bom design aí. Analisando sua necessidade e considerando apenas o que você expôs, thread aí é um exagero e de fato você não deveria tentar gerenciar threads em um container EJB.